# SEO strategy for h1, h2, h3 tags for list of items

Tags: seo

On a page on my website page I have a list of ALL the products on my site. This list is growing rapidly and I am wondering how to manage it from an SEO point of view. I am shortly adding a title to this section and giving it an H1 tag.

Currently the name of each product in this list is not h1,2,3,4 its just styled text. However I was looking to make these h2,3,4.

Questions:

1. Is the use of h2,3,4 on these list items bad form as they should be used for content rather than all links?
2. I am thinking of limiting this main list to only 8 items and using h2 tags for each name. Do you this this will have a negative or possible affect over all.
3. I may create a piece of script which counts the first 8 items on the list. These 8 will get the h2, and any after that will get h3 (all styled the same).
4. If I do add h tags should I put just on the name of the product or the outside of the a tag, therefore collecting all info.
5. Has anyone been in a similar situation as this, and if so did they really see any significant difference?

Comment: How do I view the speaker in a Grid pattern?

Comment: Just to double-check, are you using HTML5? The semantics of headers has changed quite a bit in HTML5, and would affect what advice makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DisgruntledGoat's answer is good, but I'd like to add an answer to a question you *should've* asked: **How do I let Google recognize things like product names on my pages?**

Actually, there are several ways to do that, but the one I'd recommend is [microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29).  For example, for your site you could use the [Product](http://www.schema.org/Product) and [Offer](http://www.schema.org/Offer) schemas from [schema.org](http://www.schema.org/), something like this:

```
<div class="listItem" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <a itemprop="url" title="Tannoy V4" href="/speakers/1/tannoy-v4">
        <div class="left">
            <img itemprop="image" width="173" height="130" alt="" src="images/small/TANNOY-V4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="mid">
            <div class="title" itemprop="name">
                <span itemprop="brand">Tannoy</span> <span itemprop="model">V4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="starRating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                <img width="183" height="32" alt="Five Star Rating" src="images/interface/5.gif">
                <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="now" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                <span class="listNow">Now <span itemprop="price">£280</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="save">
                <span class="listSave">Save £70</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

(If that example HTML looks familiar, it's because I grabbed it off your site and just added the bits in **boldface**.)

That said, while marking up items in lists shouldn't do any harm, what you *really* should do is add this kind of microdata markup to the individual product pages.  That way, Google can use it to generate [rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) for your pages when they appear in search results.  For more information, see [*Getting started with schema.org*](http://www.schema.org/docs/gs.html).

Comment: I have been doing so many bits and pieces I have never had the chance to sit down and read about this schema stuff! This really does make sense doesn't it... will have a look at it now! thanks again @Karonen

Comment: Very interesting indeed! Opened up a whole new way of thinking now! I see you have put '<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" />' Does that mean that on class="listItem" i should be saying what the  'bestRating' and 'worstRating' is?

Comment: Just looked up on this http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750    I think I may need to use this code to show the value of the best rating <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">  correct?

Comment: According to http://www.schema.org/AggregateRating, the best and worst ratings default to 5 and 1 respectively.

Comment: ah ok I see, sorry wasn't that clear when I first saw it. So for the details page (http://www.soundplaza.co.uk/speakers/1/tannoy-v4#) would I use the description for the description, reviews/ features, specifications, delivery, seller info or should i just keep it to reviews/ features and description?    and then URL for the link off to the site?

Comment: Schema.org describes the `description` property as "A short description of the item", so I guess you should keep it pretty short. You could always use Google's [rich snippets testing tool](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173839) to see how they parse your microdata.

Comment: ah interesting... it appears you can only have one item per page so it doesn't support multiple items sadly... i will try it on my details page... from looking at this video im guessing putting any info in a display none might be a bit risky - http://www.soundplaza.co.uk/topdeals/all-speakers/0-50000

Comment: sorry i mean this link that says not to hide spinets - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thS5ryMXN88

Comment: @TheoG: I know this might seem a bit unusual, but if you don't mind, could I please ask you to unaccept my answer and re-accept DisgruntledGoat's?  It would seem fair to me, since, whatever other respective merits our answers might have, his is the one that actually answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 6):

You are massively over thinking this, and most of what you suggest will make little to no difference.

There should be one H1 tag per page, which is the main title of the page, eg "Speaker systems".

Then each H2 should separate sections. In your case you could use an H2 for the name of each product (just the name, not the entire list block).

Lower headings should only be used if you further divide sub-sections are are rarer in practice.

To answer your questions more directly:

1. Yes it is bad form.
2. This is the proper way to do it, although you don't need to limit to 8. Around 20-30 items per page is generally expected.
3. Waste of time.
4. Just the name as stated above.
5. It doesn't make a big difference. H1 is most important, H2 may have a bit of weight, but after that there is no difference.